# Recent Files keep disappearing and off button does not work

Tags: video, power-management

I am new to Ubuntu. Installed Jellyfish as dual boot on my 2 year old media server and love it quick and smooth. I have 2 problems first being that the power off switch does not work and leaves an Ubuntu screen hanging the only solution being the off button on the PC.

Searching for a cure brings up a couple of dozen cures and I tried them all with no success. The 2nd problem is that recent video files keep disappearing. Other file types seem unaffected but even weirder is that the some of the missing video files may suddenly reappear in the folder although not all of them and may include video files that have been deleted. The recent files is set to never clear the file list. This fault is really annoying as its a media server and keeping track of what's been viewed is an important function for me.

I hold little hope for the power off problem but live in hope that the Ubuntu world has a solution for the vanishing video files

Comment: Apologies for the format of my questions I am not a techie and I can only comment on what I see and what happens. I arrived at Ubuntu after asking is there something better and yes there is. I am on a steep learning curve so please be patient with a newbie as I dont know of any other way of asking.

Comment: I removed the rant stuff.

Comment: It is not clear where the files are "disappearing" from. Is it from a list of recently viewed files, or actually from the folder?

Comment: You didn't say what Ubuntu 22.04 LTS system you installed; you mention Server, so it is Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server you installed?  You mention the power button, which implies to me you have local access (*though you could mean through a iLO type remote access too*), but if the box is local & you have keyboard; a quick shutdown is just via SysRq command direct to kernel (eg. REISUO). Clean commands like that (*a direct Linux command, not Ubuntu specific*) you should avoid file-system issues that can cause data/file loss due to power-button usage...

Comment: addition to last comment:   Some products have SysRq commands disabled by default; but you weren't specific as to what 22.04 product you installed, so it maybe a *easy* option, or may not work with changes to defaults first.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS desktop installed and also reinstalled ( twice ) , not a server or networked.

Comment: The power switch is the one that is top right of the Ubuntu screen I will research the REISUO command later to day.  The video files only disappear from the recent files folder and nowhere else

Comment: Please add additional details to your question; it mentions only *media **server*** and at no point refers to desktop; thus that is important detail. This is a Q&A (*Question & Answer*) site and not a forum, with comments being from readers to the OP or *original poster* or a prior comment, and get removed once addressed. Answers will be to your question itself (which uses the word **server** only). SysRq is a key on the keyboard (*printed on front of key & not printed at all on some newish consumer keyboards but it's there but may require Fn too*), search "magic sysrq" & read wikipedia.

Comment: Thanks giverc , some of the mysteries of sysreq now explained.   sysreq +o does indeed power down but the speed that it did about 1 sec made me wonder if the sysreq +o command is actually a safe powerdown . so I tried the reisuo command which also powered down but the speed was again a little over 1 sec. As i dont have a correctly functioning OS to compare against , is the 1 sec power down to quick or am I worrying about nothing.

Comment: The sysrq O is power off; but don't skip the other parts for a safe shutdown; eg. the S will run the `sync` process to flush disk buffers (in ram) out to disk etc. thus why I used the REISUO series of commands. As for your timing (1 sec); the time required will vary on device, storage being used, what's running etc so usually isn't constant in my experience; I aren't willing to common on your *unknown* hardware, *unknown* file-systems & *unknown* software stack (*not just OS, but what apps are running, making changes to data etc*).

Comment: Thanks again guiverc, I missed the significance of the s command, and I think we can now close this question as answered.